# Select table column based on a variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically created table and I need to select a column based on adding 150 to the value in the first column. I can find the right cell but I can't figure out how to select the column.

```js
var firstCol = $('.PriceTable td:nth-child(2)');
var firstColValue = parseInt($('.PanelHeaderPermanent:first').text(), 10);
var colThreeValue = firstColValue + 300;
var colThree = $(`td.PanelHeaderPermanent:contains("${colThreeValue}")`);




$(firstCol).addClass('showCol');
$(colThree).addClass('showCol');
```

```css
.showCol {
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  display: table-cell!important;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="FullWidth" border="0">
<tr>
<td align="left"></td><td align="right"><table class="PriceTable FullWidth" border="0">
<tr>
<td></td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">150+</td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">160+</td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">170+</td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">180+</td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">190+</td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">200+</td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">210+</td><td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">220+</td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="right">Your Price</td><td><span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span itemprop="price">2.44</span></td><td>$2.44</td><td>$2.43</td><td>$2.43</td><td>$2.42</td><td>$2.42</td><td>$2.41</td><td>$2.41</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by select the column? Apply CSS styling?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to select the column **190+** obtained adding 40 to value of first column **150+**

You can get the index of such cell:

```
var colThreeIdx = $('td.PanelHeaderPermanent:contains("' + colThreeValue + '")').index() + 1;
```

and so select the column:

```
var colThree = $('.PriceTable td:nth-child(' + colThreeIdx + ')');
```

The snippet:

```js
var firstCol = $('.PriceTable td:nth-child(2)');
var firstColValue = parseInt($('.PanelHeaderPermanent:first').text(), 10);
var colThreeValue = firstColValue + 40;
var colThreeIdx = $('td.PanelHeaderPermanent:contains("' + colThreeValue + '")').index() + 1;
var colThree = $('.PriceTable td:nth-child(' + colThreeIdx + ')');




$(firstCol).addClass('showCol');
$(colThree).addClass('showCol');
```

```css
.showCol {
    border: 1px dashed purple;
    display: table-cell!important;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="FullWidth" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"></td>
        <td align="right">
            <table class="PriceTable FullWidth" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">150+</td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">160+</td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">170+</td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">180+</td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">190+</td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">200+</td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">210+</td>
                    <td class="PanelHeaderPermanent">220+</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Your Price</td>
                    <td><span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span itemprop="price">2.44</span></td>
                    <td>$2.44</td>
                    <td>$2.43</td>
                    <td>$2.43</td>
                    <td>$2.42</td>
                    <td>$2.42</td>
                    <td>$2.41</td>
                    <td>$2.41</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly